# Ruby on Rails - grouped_collection_select error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby on Rails and still unfamilar with some of parts of the language. Using the grouped_collection_select I am trying to filter all the relevant models for a specific make of car...

I am unsure if the grouped_collection_select has the correct parameters and if they are in the correct order as I encounter this error and cannot seem to resolve it : "undefined method `map' for "3 Series":String".

Also I am using this [railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1zZ4Lgzf9s) and already have the Javascript added to the relevant file.

app\views_multi_search.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag ('make_id'), 
        options_from_collection_for_select(@makes, :id, :makes_info, 0 ),
        :prompt => "Select a Make" %>
<%#= select_tag ('model_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@models, :id, :model_info, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Select a Model" %>

<%= select_tag ('model_id'), grouped_collection_select(:model,:model_id,Model.all,:model_info,:model,:id,:model),:prompt => "Select a Model" %>
```

Calling the partial in application.html.erb:

`

```
<%= render( :partial => '/multi_search', 
            :locals => {
            :makes => @makes = Make.all,:models => @models = Model.all,
            :my_path => '/cars/multi_find' })%>'
```

The model code for the make and car model:

make.rb

```
class Make < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :cars
    has_many :model
```

model:rb

```
has_many :cars
    belongs_to :make

    has_many :cars
    belongs_to :make
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

one thing that you need to do is in your Make class write

```
has_many :models
```

instead of

```
has_many :model
```

Comment: Thank you! Any other improvements?